# Dynamics CRM Quote products Add Products VIEW - New column not loading value

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft365

I added a new column to the Quote Product entity and it's a calculated field
[image]

[image]

And add that field to the add product view
[image]

My problem is Quote products Add Products not picking the calculated value
[image]

Comment: Did you add a formula?

Comment: Yes added to the formula to the new field. and it shows data correctly in the Quote product form.